# Connecting to Solace using paho-mqtt (JavaScript)

Tags: websocket, mqtt, solace

I'm running an example solace broker (using the command [here](https://solace.com/get-started)) and trying to connect to it from a web browser. I've succeeded in connecting to it using the client libraries, but I understand it should be possible to connect to it using the paho-mqtt library. Unfortunately, all the examples are for the Java library, which uses a different connection API. Does anyone have an example that literally just called "mqtt.Connect" and gets a successful return code?

Comment: Edit the question to show us what you've tried. Also include the connection information you provided to the other client libraries

Comment: Does Solace support MQTT over WebSockets?

Comment: Good question. This suggests the answer is yes: https://solace.com/products/apis-protocols/

Comment: You still need to edit the question with what I asked for yesterday if you want help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solace totally supports the Eclipse Paho MQTT libs... the problem is that quick-and-dirty getting started on that page (new location: https://solace.com/software/getting-started/) doesn't expose all the ports you need.  Unfortunately, Docker needs the exposed (published) ports defined at create time (unless you're on a Linux machine and you created your Docker container with "host" networking).  So if you're on Docker for Windows or Docker for Mac, you'll have to recreate your container.

The default MQTT non-TLS WebSockets port is 8000.  (There's a whole bunch more: https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/SW-Broker-Specific-Config/SW-Broker-Configuration-Defaults.htm).  So your container create command will be something like:

`docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 8080:8080 -p 55555:55555 -p:80:80 --shm-size=2g --env username_admin_globalaccesslevel=admin --env username_admin_password=admin --name=solacePSPlusStandard solace/solace-pubsub-standard`

That should allow your Paho JS API to connect!  Maybe add 1883 (MQTT over TCP) and 9000 (REST messaging) ports as well, just in case.